# Flutter Navigate & Send Data Between Custom Dialogs

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to navigate & send data between 2 consecutive dialogs.
Current Code:

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => SendLeadTargetWidget(),
    );
},
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the proper way of doing it. I thought maybe there would be a solution with named routes or something like that. Later on I will also be passing data between both so I wanted to now if anyone had a proper way of doing a navigation of this kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set up your class like this:

```
  class SendLeadTargetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
     final String data;

     const SendLeadTargetWidget({Key key, this.data})
      : super(key: key);

     @override
     SendLeadTargetWidgetState createState() =>
        _ SendLeadTargetWidgetState();
}
```

and pass the variable in this way:

```
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
   showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (_) => SendLeadTargetWidget(data: dataString),
   );
 },
```